# Call arguments received by layer 'max_pooling3d_80' (type MaxPooling3D)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is my class for feature extraction using CNN

```
import copy
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D
import tensorflow


class FeatureExtraction:
    def __init__(self, images: list):
        self.images = images
        self.model_big = None
        self.model_small = None
        self.images_extracted_BIG_model = list()
        self.images_extracted_SMALL_model = list()

    def cnn_model_big(self):
        model = Sequential()

        # Start with input of shape 128x128x128x1 (the '1' signifies a single channel, e.g., grayscale)
        model.add(Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 128, 1), padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))  # Output size: 64x64x64

        model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))  # Output size: 32x32x32

        model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))  # Output size: 16x16x16

        model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
        # Apply a pooling layer with a custom stride to reach the desired output size of 12x12x12
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 1, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1)))

        self.model_big = copy.deepcopy(model)

    def cnn_model_small(self):
        model = Sequential()

        # Input shape: 64x64x64x1 (assuming a single channel, like grayscale)
        model.add(Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 64, 1), padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))  # Output size: 32x32x32

        model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))  # Output size: 16x16x16

        model.add(Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))  # Output size: 8x8x8

        model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
        # Custom stride to reach the desired output size of 6x6x6
        model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same'))

        model.summary()

        self.model_small = copy.deepcopy(model)

    def feature_extraction(self, status: str = "SMALL"):
        if status == "BIG":
            images_array = np.array([img.reshape(128, 128, 128, 1) for img in self.images])
            self.cnn_model_big()
            for img in images_array:
                predicted_img = self.model_big.predict(img)
                self.images_extracted_BIG_model.append(copy.deepcopy(predicted_img))
        elif status == "SMALL":
            images_array = np.array([img.reshape(64, 64, 64, 1) for img in self.images])
            self.cnn_model_small()
            for img in images_array:
                print(img.shape)
                predicted_img = self.model_small.predict(img)
                self.images_extracted_SMALL_model.append(copy.deepcopy(predicted_img))
        else:
            raise Exception("NOT VALID STATUS")
```

I have a list of images that contains 388 images which are 64*64*64.
when I want to convert my images to 6*6*6 using this model here is the error I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[43], line 3
      1 # BIG feature extraction
      2 BIG_feature_extraction = FeatureExtraction(preprocessed_images_BIG)
----> 3 BIG_images_features = BIG_feature_extraction.feature_extraction()
      5 # SMALL feature extraction
      6 SMALL_feature_extraction = FeatureExtraction(preprocessed_images_SMALL)

Cell In[42], line 68
     66     for img in images_array:
     67         print(img.shape)
---> 68         predicted_img = self.model_small.predict(img)
     69         self.images_extracted_SMALL_model.append(copy.deepcopy(predicted_img))
     70 else:

File e:\tuts\Bio_Informatics\Research\ICB12\BIO_DAT_SCAN_ANALYSIS\.env\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileyd064d2j.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__predict_function(iterator)
...
    Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node sequential_20/max_pooling3d_80/MaxPool3D}} = MaxPool3D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NDHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]](sequential_20/conv3d_80/Relu)' with input shapes: [32,64,64,1,1].
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'max_pooling3d_80' (type MaxPooling3D):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 64, 64, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

in this class, I implemented two types of CNN models which take 128*128*128 images and convert them to 12*12*12 arrays, and one small model that takes 64*64*64 arrays and converts them to 6*6*6 images. but when I pass my list of images to this code here, here is the error I get, how ever the shape of my image list is 388*64*64*64, I really can not see what is the problem